# Number of six digit numbers divisible by $3$ but none of the digits is $3$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, permutations, binomial-coefficients

Find number of six digit numbers divisible by $3$ but none of the digits is $3$

My try:

Let the six digits are $a,b,c,d,e,f$ such that

$$a+b+c+d+e+f=3p$$

where $1 \le p \le 18$

Now since $a \ge 1$ we have by Stars and Bars Technique number of solutions of the above equation as:

$$S=\sum_{p=1}^{18}\binom{3p+4}{5}$$

But if we use Exclusion method, its very lengthy.

Any hint?

Comment: Are leading $0$'s allowed?

Comment: I assume the OP meant that the leading digit is $a$ and he specified that it is $\ge 1$ , so no leading zeros.

Comment: Yes $a$ is the first digit from left

Comment: Either the number of digits $\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ is the same as the number  $\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ or one is $0$ and the other is $6$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Excluding $3$, there are exactly three digits congruent to each of $0,1$ and $2$ $\pmod 3$.

Let the first $5$ digits be whatever you like (excluding $3$)   There are $8\times 9^4$ such numbers (trusting that the string can not start with $0$).  Now we choose the final digit in order to make the sum of the digits $0\pmod 3$.  For each given prefix, there are exactly $3$ ways to do that.  Thus the answer is $$3\times 8\times 9^4$$

Comment: Excellent.  You posted this just in time to save me embarking on a long calculation.  I feel like an idiot.

Comment: @saulspatz  It's curious that the trick only works because we exclude one of the digits $\equiv 0 \pmod 3$.  If, say, you excluded $1$, I think you're back to your lengthy computation.

Comment: Yes, I think that's right.

Comment: Oh great stack exchange has really great brains

Comment: This blew my mind. +1!

Answer (score 1):

The digits we can use to form these numbers are $$\{0, 1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9\}\equiv \{0, 1, 2,1, 2,0,1,2,0\}\pmod3$$

Let $S$ be the sum of the last five digits,

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
S\bmod3 & \color{blue}0 & \color{red}1 & \color{green}2 \\
\text{Probability} & 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\
\end{array}
$$

Observe that the first digit $\in\{1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9\}\equiv\{\color{green}1,\color{red}2,\color{green}1,\color{red}2,\color{blue}0,\color{green}1,\color{red}2,\color{blue}0\}\bmod3$.

Therefore, the probability, that a six digit number - from the ones we are considering -  is divisible by $3$ is $$P=\color{blue}{\frac13\cdot\frac28}+\color{red}{\frac13\cdot\frac38}+\color{green}{\frac13\cdot\frac38}=\frac{8}{24}=\frac13$$ Therefore, exactly one third of all numbers - from the ones we are considering - is divisible by $3$...